# Clicking outside a textBox or button force closes my app with IllegalStateException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-sdk-2.3

Below is the Java file that I used.  All of the code works really well, but the error above still lingers.  Can anyone see the problem?

```
package tip.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TipCalculator extends Activity 
{
    private Button enter;
    EditText myEditField;
    EditText myEditField2;
    float percentage = 0;
    float percentageInp = 0;
    float billAmount = 0;
    double output = 0; 
    String output1 = "";
    Button clearButton ;
    TextView textView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
        enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        myEditField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.billText);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);

        enter.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView errors;
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                errors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
                int a = 0;
                if(myEditField2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    errors.setText("Error");
                } else {
                    a++;
                }

                if(myEditField.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    errors.setText("Error");
                } else {
                    a++;
                }

                if(a == 2) {
                    percentageInp = Float.parseFloat(myEditField.getText().toString());
                    billAmount = Float.parseFloat(myEditField2.getText().toString());
                    percentage = ((float)percentageInp /100);

                    output = (double)(billAmount * percentage);

                    double result = output * 100;
                    result = Math.round(result);
                    result = result / 100;

                    output1 = Double.toString(result);

                    View.setText(output1 + " $");
                    errors.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        clearButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView errors;
                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                errors = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
                int a = 0;

                if (myEditField2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    myEditField.setText("");
                    percentage = 0;
                    percentageInp = 0;
                    billAmount = 0;
                    output = 0; 
                    textView.setText("");
                    output1 = "";
                } else {
                    a++;
                }

                if(myEditField.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    myEditField2.setText("");
                    percentage = 0;
                    percentageInp = 0;
                    billAmount = 0;
                    output = 0; 
                    output1 = "";
                    textView.setText("");
                 } else {
                    a++;
                 }

                 if (a == 2) {
                    myEditField.setText("");
                    myEditField2.setText("");
                    percentage = 0;
                    percentageInp = 0;
                    billAmount = 0;
                    output = 0; 
                    output1 = "";

                    textView.setText("");
                    errors.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the logcat, where I get an error I don't understand at all. I never call the method *`onEnterClick()`*?

```
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onEnterClick(View) in the activity class tip.calculator.TipCalculator for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout with id 'errorText'
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3085)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onEnterClick [class android.view.View]
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3078)
08-02 21:17:37.205: E/AndroidRuntime(27185):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Have you used any `onClick` attribute to anywhere in your `activity_main` layout?

Comment: @SpK there was one earlier for this so i deleted it, because i wasn't using it

Comment: Try to clean your project. And, run it again. And, show your `activity_main` layout here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have defined the onclick method in the XML Layout also. And you have written the onclick listener in the program. Remove the following line from your xml layout and your program works fine:

```
android:onclick="onEnterClick"
```

Comment: Can you able to put your xml file now

Answer (score 1):

This because of you're setting `android:onClick="onEnterClick"` to your `RelativeLayout` And, you didn't implement this in your `TipCalculator.java` file. So, there you've an exception with `IllegalStateException` See your `LogCat`'s first line -

> Could not find a method onEnterClick(View) in the activity class tip.calculator.TipCalculator for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout with id 'errorText'

You can easily understand with above line of exception.

Comment: @PrommeringsDisplay Show me the `XML` part

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you have declared a function onEnterClick in your Button layout in xml . There will be a line like `android:onClick="onEnterClick` in your button layout.

So define the action you want when you press that button, inside

```
public void onEnterClick(View view)
```

in your java class.

note: you first have to create this function.